# FileNotFoundError on file upload using Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, image-uploading, wsgi

I am using Flask as a backend for a mobile application, and one of its feature is uploading and renaming images for profile pictures and post media attachment

Lately, the upload webservices return `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` with a `500 Error` when using them on the development server

I don't really think it's a code issue as it works fine on my local environment, but it crashes over there.

This is the traceback from the dev server

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/var/www/xxxxx.com/xxxxx/controllers/posts.py", line 14, in posts
    return posts_service.post(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_jwt/__init__.py", line 177, in decorator
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/xxxxx.com/xxxxx/services/posts.py", line 82, in post
    file.save(filepath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 2800, in save
    dst = open(dst, "wb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xxxxx/uploads/fc23dfb1-6852-47cc-9090-4aa80a1f1d9d.jpe'
```

And here is the post function

```py
@jwt_required()
def post(request):
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return {
            'success': False,
            'message': 'No file part in the request',
        }, 200
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return {
            'success': False,
            'message': 'No file selected for uploading',
        }, 200
    if file and allowed_file(file.mimetype):
        filepath = makepath(file.mimetype)
        file.save(filepath)
        post = post_repo.create(
            current_identity.id,
            request.form['matchId'],
            request.form['teamSelected'],
            request.form['content'],
            request.form['postType'],
            filepath,
            request.form['location']
        )
        if post:
            return {
                'success': True,
                'message': 'Post successfully created',
                'post': post_repo.to_dto(post),
            }, 201
    return {
        'success': False,
        'message': 'File extension not allowed',
    }, 200
```

I have already chmoded the uploads directory to be writeable by `others`

The dev environment is hosted within a docker environment using apache 2.4 and wsgi in order to serve it

What should I ask the server administrators to check in there?

**Edit:** I just noticed that when I `ls -la` the directory, there is no group column. Could that be why the uploads are not working?

```
[echo] Check final permissions
[exec] drwxr-xrwx 2 33 www-data 4096 Feb 10 09:35 .
[exec] drwxr-xr-x 12 33 www-data 4096 Feb 10 09:35 ..
[exec] -rw-r--r-- 1 33 www-data 1791 Feb 10 09:35 726f052d-2ad8-41cd-98fa-41eb2c9ba728.png
[exec] -rw-r--r-- 1 33 www-data 12605 Feb 10 09:35 camera.jpg
[exec] -rw-r--r-- 1 33 www-data 4208 Feb 10 09:35 camera.png
```

**Update:** As suggested in the comments, I have tried using absolute path when using the save function, which resulted in an odd error message in the stacktrace, it generated something else, like this `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/xxxxx/uploads/b94a6fd0-af54-45f1-95d4-5cbe1dc7ca38.jpe'`, adding a / just before the folder name, and it makes sense why it would fail here, as that path doesn't exist on the server

Comment: looks like permission problem, maybe you should try to modify owner and group (chown), it is set for user 33 group www-data

Comment: @warungman ok, so I'm deploying to the server using jenkins, using lftp to send the files out there, but it seems I can't use neither chown nor sudo using lftp commands

Comment: Humm, try use absolute path in your Flask projects, i has this problem in PythonAnywhere server, just use 'basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
'

Comment: @CaioFilus just tried your approach, still works fine on my local, stil fails on the server

Comment: We'd have to know how the `makepath()` function is implemented, probably...